# Why can't the compiler convert from a derived class to it's interface when trying to use a Dictionary of interfaces as a method parameter?

Tags: c#, dictionary, inheritance, c#-4.0, interface

I'm trying to pass a `Dictionary<string, Derived>` into a method that expects a `Dictionary<string, IBase>`. When i do this, the compiler throws the following error message

`cannot convert from Dictionary<string, Derived> to Dictionary<string, IBase>`

Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. The compilation error happens where I call `Test(aDict);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var aDict = new Dictionary<string, Derived>();
        Test(aDict);
    }

    void Test(Dictionary<string, IBase> dict)
    {}
}

public interface IBase
{}

public class Derived : IBase
{}
```

If someone can show me how to do this without getting the exception, or explain why it can't be done in c#, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it *could*. Also assume there's *another* class, `EvilDerived` that implements `IBase`. And suppose `Test` did this:

```
void Test(Dictionary<string, IBase> dict)
{
    dict.Add("EvliKey", new EvilDerived());
}
```

The code within `Test` is perfectly valid, but the dictionary that's passed in can only hold `Derived` objects as its value, so it can't hold an `EvilDerived` as a value. What should happen then?

You *might* be able to get around it by making `Test` generic and restrict the value type to a (singular) implementation of `IBase`:

```
void Test<T>(Dictionary<string, T> dict) where T : IBase
{}
```

but since you don't show what you're *doing* with `Test` it's impossible to know if that would work for you.